# Как передать данные из одного потока в другой? - pthread.h - С

Tags: c, многопоточность, pthread

Запущен поток, предположим в функции main():

```
void* threadFunc(void* args) {
  int* status = (int*) args[1];
  while(1) {
    //...
    // в неопределенный момент времени ей присваивается значение
    *status = 2; 
    //...
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread;
  // указатель на эту переменную мы передаем в поток
  int status = 1;
  //...
  while (1) {
    if (a == 2)
      printf("Наконец ты равна 2, спасибо!");
  }
  //...
  return 0;
}
```

Как я понимаю если так сделать то: как минимум у нас переменная может быть потребована двумя разными процессами одновременно и может получить случайное значение. Я читал про атомарные операции, но очень плохо понял, так как не видел конкретного примера. Также слышал о mutex, тоже хотел бы разобраться.

Или возможно для конкретно этой ситуации лучше использовать другой способ? Можно ли как-то по-другому выводить статус выполнения потоковой функции в другой поток?

Comment: Запись в такую переменную (int) в большинстве архитектур будет [атомарна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).  mutex это объект (поддержка обеспечивается ОС), который служит для синхронизации потоков. Если при операции блокирования mutex свободен, то поток захватывает его и продолжает выполняться. Если mutex занят, то поток приостанавливается до того момента, пока другой поток (хозяин блокировки) не освободит mutex. Теперь владельцем блокировки будет поток, продолживший выполняться

Comment: у нас в городе есть одна компания, которая делает софт для автомобилей и там "сеньйоры" верят в то, что int атомарный и volatile помогает при многопоточности. Но вот только misra запрещает им людей калечить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень плохо, когда люди пишут слишком маленькие примеры и сидишь и гадаешь, как они это скомпилили. Ведь args это void*,а для него адресная арифметика просто так не работает... и комплиятор об этом должен был сказать... Но ничего, восстановим пример сами. Вот начнем с такого прямолинейного (**он чуточку неверный, ниже исправим**).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* threadFunc(void* args) {
  int* status = (int*) args;
  while(1) {
    //...
    // в неопределенный момент времени ей присваивается значение
    sleep(1);
    *status = 2;
    //...
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread;
  // указатель на эту переменную мы передаем в поток
  int status = 1;
  int ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunc, &status);
  if (ret != 0) {
      perror("cat't create thread");
      return 1;
  }
  while (1) {
    if (status == 2) {
      printf("Наконец ты равна 2, спасибо!");
      break;
    }
  }
  //...
  return 0;
}
```

компилим

```
gcc th.c -pthread
```

если это запустить, то оно отработает секунду (то есть, все как бы стработало), но ничего не выведет...

А потому что строка осталась в буфере, а не то, что подумали большинство пользователей (переменная была оптимизированна, скажет грозный минусатор и будет не не совсем прав).

Заменяем на `printf` на `puts` или добавляем перевод строки и все работает. Но как то не то....

а теперь скомпилируем с `-O1` и все... оно повисло... Потому что компилятор видит, что переменная не меняется и имеет право оптимизировать... ох уж эти компиляторы... вечно что то оптимизируют.

Исправить (это не совсем правильное слово в данном контексте) это можно по разному. Есть два основных способа - атомарные переменные и мютексы, также есть условные переменные и один неверный способ - через volatile. Но не стоит их использовать. Да, в этом примере оно  наверно будет работать почти всегда, но volatile и многопоточность - перпендикулярные вещи.

Вот хороший пример с атомиками. я убрал некоторые проверки, что бы сделать код проще

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

void* threadFunc(void* args) {
  _Atomic int* status = (_Atomic int*) args;
  while(1) {
    sleep(1);
    atomic_store(status, 2);
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread;
  _Atomic int status;
  atomic_init(&status, 1);
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunc, &status);
  while (1) {
    if (atomic_load(&status) == 2) {
      puts("Наконец ты равна 2, спасибо!");
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, вы уж людей совсем с volatile не пугайте. По крайней мере в gcc он заставляет компилятор генерить код с  обращением к памяти. А atomic_store длбавит после записи барьер синхронизации памяти (иногда (например, в реализации spin-off mutex) это в самом деле нужно, иногда нет, вполне и без таких задержек будет работать)

Comment: я не пугаю. Но только volatile в gcc не добавляет никаких барьеров. И это может быть печально. Поэтому, лучше сразу прививать правильный стиль.

Comment: В чем-то вы правы (по крайней мере наша прибыль от такого софта будет только расти)

Comment: Просто если эта переменная status используется для остановки потока или просто нотификации - ок. с volatile оно почти всегда будет работать. Но если к примеру, поток вначале что то долго и нудно считал, а потом выставил эту переменную как признак конца расчета, то тут могут быть проблемы. Даже если сами расчеты тоже записываются в volatile переменную, то в другом потоке они могут быть готовы в противоположном порядке и хотя переменные как будто будут выставлены правильно, но при чтении будет прочитан мусор или предыдущее значение. А атомик для status все сделает как надо (ну почти).

Comment: Не очень понятно, как это смоделировать (такое запаздывание в синхронизации кэша), но в принципе, наверное, возможно.

Comment: легко. Достаточно, что бы две переменные попали в разные линии кеша. И тогда нет гарантии, что они будут сброшены так, как того ожидает погроммист. да да, это не опечатка

Comment: В самом деле MESI (или его разновидность) настолько асинхронны (я имею в виду обычную SMP систему)? К сожалению, я знаю эти протоколы только в общих чертах.

Comment: @avp, **KoVadim** наблюдаемую ситуацию правильно описывает, но дело не в кешах — AFAIK их когерентность на всех простых архитектурах обеспечивается корректно... дело в out-of-order исполнении; правда на x86 связанные с этим проблемы поймать почти невозможно, а вот на arm'е — запросто...

Comment: я думаю, если очень сильно закопаться, то можно все это раскрыть, но думаю, для автора вопроса уже достаточно далеко зашли.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, согласен, спасибо